# Updatepanel stylesheet

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Inside the update panel I have update progess I want to set stylesheet inside the updatepanel like following I want to set vertical-align to middle but I it is not work how I can repair this code ?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="Server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="300px" Visible="false" />
      <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
          <ProgressTemplate>
              <div style="vertical-align:middle;">
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/img/loading.gif" />
                    Please Wait...</div>
           </ProgressTemplate>
       </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the page in Firebug add-on for firefox to make sure that the style has been applied? There is every chance that the style has been applied but it is not doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: yes I agree with you but as you know firefox is different browser perhaps it is applied in firefox but not applied in IE so what ?

Comment: If it is applied in one browser it will be "applied" to the element in both browsers. The difference between the browsers is almost always how the applied styles are interpreted and then rendered once they have been applied. The first thing to check is whether Firefox identifies that the element "has the style". Then you need to see what it does with it, and how this differs to what IE does with it. In your case, it is to do with the box rendering of images. I have tested my CSS answer below and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical-align:middle; style will not have any effect on the image. What you probably want to do is add a CssClass="loadingimage" to the image and apply the following to it:

```
.loadingimage  {
     float:left;
     margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Also, add some padding to the div:

```
  <div style="padding:4px;">
      <asp:Image ID="Image3" CssClass="loadingimage" 
          runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/img/loading.gif"  />
      <span>Please Wait...</span>
  </div>
```